# Grafana - How to filter data by time

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

How to filter data with  1d interval. I'm trying to create bar chart with my PV system production and I need last value of day_kWh field over past 7 days.
e.g:
[image]

So far my code looks like this:

```
from(bucket: "GrowattBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Growatt 4000TL3-S")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "day_kWh")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check with your data... but try this:

```
   |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: last)
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.